# Light ecaping the event horizon by means of diffraction

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, laser, event-horizon

Is it possible to calculate if at the event horizon a hypotethical diffraction bending of a laser beam tangential to the black hole can counterpose a gravitational bending of the same beam?.....

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to calculate if at the event horizon a hypotethical diffraction bending of a laser beam tangential to the black hole can counterpose a gravitational bending of the same beam?.....

No, you can't evade the event horizon this way. The solution of an initial-value problem for a wave equation in GR depends only on the initial conditions that lie within the past light cone. The fundamental significance of the metric in GR is that it dictates all possible cause-and-effect relationships. In your example, all of the diffraction fringes will lie within the horizon.

Comment: Am I right in pressuming that the outer part of the beam will tend to the diffraction angle limit even in vicinity of the event horizon?....Ofcourse the gravity bending will alter the trajectory but I am asking about the resultant trajectory.... will the result lie somewhere between two  extremes?